# xpath XML parser is not parsing anything, neither does give any debug info

Tags: feeds

Mappings:
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s61/sh/3e900019-a2c7-4a10-bc1c-0868341c4d9d/a735396d74047a86da8668c34c7a9f7d

Source feed:
https://www.monosnap.com/image/BmKv9p9ao4hua1wvWpRh2pl85

For some reason I can't get it to import anything. What am I missing?

Tried also context: //channel/item.

Feed path: http://poliisi.fi/poliisi/kanta-hame/home.nsf/feedrss.xml

This is very simple and basic feed which is giving me a major headache currently. Maybe a fresh pair of eyes is smarter than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Module had some odd bug. Cloning earlier working importer and changing it identical to above worked.